# remove default margin in inline block elements?

Tags: html, css

code:

```
<div style={{margin:'20px auto 20px auto', textAlign: 'center'}}>
 {this.state.boxes.map((item,index) => {
  return (<div 
  key={index} 
  style={{display: 'inline-block',boxSizing:'borderBox', border: "solid #333 1px", height: '130px', width: '130px', position: 'relative'}} > </div>)
  })}
</div>
```

but as you can see there's a little space on top and bottom in the middle? 
[image]

Comment: Set `font-size` to `0`. Alternative solutions to explore: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Have you also reset the line-height to 1?

Comment: I'll try ur suggestions, I gues it's some default behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want like this

```css
.outer{
  margin:20px auto 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 260px;
}
.inner{
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid #333 1px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 33.33%; 
  box-sizing : border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.pull-left{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner pull-left"></div>
  <div class="inner pull-left"></div>
  <div class="inner pull-left"></div>
  <div class="inner pull-left"></div>
  <div class="inner pull-left"></div>
  <div class="inner pull-left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! the linked question answers were too complicated

Answer (score 1):

Set `font-size:0;` to outer division. It will remove the extra spacings.

Answer (score 1):

A trick I learnt when doing my website designs is to use the following:

```
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-size:0px;
    border:solid black 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Some of you may disagree because now you have to reset padding and etc to the elements and its time consuming the reason I do this is because browsers view things differently maybe by a few `px` and stuff so using this can help reset styles to avoid coming across those browser issues you can add as much `css` styles in there it will be applied to everything.